# Multiple same-line is operators

Tags: python, operator-keyword

I understand that the `is` operator is used to check whether one object points to the same memory address as another. Consider this following example:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 10
>>> x is x
True
>>> x is y
False
>>> id(x)
499843696
>>> id(y)
499843856
```

Fair enough. But then I tried this comparison:

```
>>> x is x is x
True
```

I'm not sure why that evaluates to `True`. It's obviously dissimilar to this:

```
>>> (x is x) is x
False
```

Because `(x is x)` returns `True` and `(True) is x` when `x` is 5 will return `False`. So what is happening in the `x is x is x` line? For comparison's sake:

```
>>> x is x is y
False
```

Is this syntax basically checking whether each object compared points to the memory address? I'm curious as to how that syntax is evaluated across the line.

Comment: Chained comparisons execute as `(x is x) and (x is x)` (but the middle `x` is only evaluated once).

Comment: @Cleared on my Python 3.6 x is x is y gives False. As for the question - I never really thought of this - just knew that its a way how it works :) if you try: x = a then x is x is a is x is a etc as well gives True so I assume Python just compares whole statement not the result (True/False) against following values, and it seems logical to me :)  Anyway - nested is usage is rare - at least in my practice